# Remove an even/odd number from an odd/even Python list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to better understand list comprehension in Python.  I completed an online challenge on codewars with a rather inelegant solution, given below.

The challenge was:

1. Given a list of even numbers and one odd, return the odd
2. Given a list of odd numbers and one even, return the even

My (inelegant) solution to this was:

```
def find_outlier(integers):
    o = []
    e = []
    for i in integers:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            e.append(i)
        else:
            o.append(i)
    # use sums to return int type
    if len(o) == 1:
        return sum(o)
    else:
        return sum(e)
```

Which works fine, but seems to be pretty brute force.  Am I wrong in thinking that starting (most) functions with placeholder lists like `o` and `e` is pretty "noob-like"?

I would love to better understand why this solution works for the odd list, but fails on the even list, in an effort to better understand list comprehension:

```
def find_outlier(integers):
    if [x for x in integers if x % 2 == 0]:
       return [x for x in integers if x % 2 == 0]
    elif [x for x in integers if x % 2 != 0]:
       return [x for x in integers if x % 2 != 0]
    else:
        print "wtf!"

o = [1,3,4,5]
e = [2,4,6,7]

In[1]: find_outlier(o)
Out[1]: [4]

In[2]: find_outlier(e)
Out[2]: [2, 4, 6]
```

Where `Out[2]` should be returning `7`.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: List comprehensions are not the best solution here, no. Try to solve it instead with the minimum number of elements checked (the first 2 elements, if they differ in type get a 3rd to break the tie, otherwise iterate until you find the one that doesn't fit in the tail).

Comment: What should happen if the `integers` list contains at least 2 even *and* 2 odd numbers? I'm pretty sure you do **not** want to just print `wtf`. I suggest you either return a meaningful value (I dunno: the empty list?) or just raise an exception and let the caller handle it. Adding `print` statements isn't a really effective way of handling errors and debugging the code...

Comment: In this particular case, there will always be *only* one odd/even in the even/odd list. @MartijnPieters still contemplating your iteration suggestion.

Comment: @D8Amonk That's the kind of assumption that *will* introduce bugs. Sure: you *assume* that, but if you at some point mistype a `178` with a `17` when writing a list you can easily end up, without knowing it, in that case and if you don't check for that you can get the wrong result. It's better to be safe than sorry and raise an exception, especially in a caselike this where checking that condition is part of the computation so you basically have no performance loss.

Comment: @Bakuriu point well received.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can I put in a solution I just found and have you sharp-shoot it?

Comment: @D8Amonk: you are always welcome to self-answer :-) Do cover the 'why did my function fail' case too though; you are writing this for people with the same problem.

Comment: @Bakuriu: since this is a coding challenge, I think the code can assume there is just one outlier.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yet the question and answer should be useful not just to the OP. Other people may have to solve the same problem but in a real-life context, in which case the better solution is the one that handle error cases too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is true; that said I think it's a good caveat given here (by many of you) that generalization and error handling should always be in the back of my mind.  although I am really enjoying the gains from sites like codewars and codefights, the test cases can be somewhat "comforting" :D

Comment: @Bakuriu: even in real-life, it could be that *ignoring* the case where the input contains more than one exception is fine. For my solution, all you need is to then assert the remainder passed to a recursive call raises `StopIteration`, but that'd then kill the performance gain of not having to test every value in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt fails because the first `if` is *always going to be true*. You'll always have a list with at least 1 element; either the odd one out is odd and you tested a list with all even numbers, otherwise you have a list with the *one* even number in it. Only an *empty* list would be false.

List comprehensions are not the best solution here, no. Try to solve it instead with the minimum number of elements checked (the first 2 elements, if they differ in type get a 3rd to break the tie, otherwise iterate until you find the one that doesn't fit in the tail):

```
def find_outlier(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    first = next(it)
    second = next(it)
    parity = first % 2
    if second % 2 != parity:
        # odd one out is first or second, 3rd will tell which
        return first if next(it) % 2 != parity else second
    else:
        # the odd one out is later on; iterate until we find the exception
        return next(i for i in it if i % 2 != parity)
```

The above will throw a `StopIteration` exception if there are either fewer than 3 elements in the input iterable, or there is no exception to be found. It also won't handle the case where there is more than one exception (e.g. 2 even followed by 2 odd; the first odd value would be returned in that case).

Comment: I submitted this to the [codewars kata in question](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/5567bb44bbb6cdc5d2000022/groups/57ebdcfb2d45a06f8c000485).

Comment: can you point me in a good direction to understand the `parity` concept/naming convention?

Comment: @D8Amonk: the kata uses the same term; it's the mathematical definition for odd and even. See [the dictionary definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parity) (meaning 4).

Answer (score 0):

What are the shortcomings of this response (which is at the top of the solution stack on [this particular challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/find-the-parity-outlier/solutions/python))?

```
def find_outlier(int):
    odds = [x for x in int if x%2!=0]
    evens= [x for x in int if x%2==0]
    return odds[0] if len(odds)<len(evens) else evens[0]
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters this was the top-voted solution.  I hadn't seen it when I wrote mine, but it's adding to my confusion as to why mine doesn't work since it seems to use the same list-comp logic I was attempting...

Comment: This partitions the list into two and uses `len()` to compare which one is shorter. Your code assumes that one of these is going to be *empty*, which is a wrong assumption.

Comment: Note that this has to process *all* values in the input list. Twice. Mine only has to process the list until an exception is found. That could be as little as the first 3 elements. Try this with `[1, 3, 4] + list(range(5, 1000000, 2))`.

Comment: I note that this may be top-voted on codewars, but the comments show that this really shouldn't be at the top. It is really costly in view of the description stating the input can be large.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm starting to understand the reason for using your iterator...still absorbing the debate on OP comments though...

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient answer is going to get a little ugly.

```
def f(in_list):
    g = (i for i in in_list)
    first = next(g)
    second = next(g) #The problem as described doesn't make sense for fewer than 3 elements.  Let them handle the exceptions.
    if first%2 == second%2:
        a = first%2
        for el in g:
            if el%2 != a:
                return el
    else:
        third = next(g)
        if third%2 == first%2:
            return second
        else:
            return first
    except ValueError('Got a bad list, all evens or all odds')
```

Comment: `(i for i in in_list)` is better written as `iter(in_list)`, no need to use a generator expression here. You can store the parity (`a` in your code) and use it for both branches.